number of primitive prime divisor
Let $q = p^n$ for some prime number $p > 2$.
According to Zsigmondy's theorem, for the number $q - 1$ there is at least one prime primitive divisor, that is, a number $r$ such that $\operatorname{ord}_{r}p = n.$
Question: is there an estimate for the number of such primitive prime divisors?
This problem is equivalent to the following: what are the estimates for the number
$$|\lbrace r \in \mathbb{P} : \operatorname{ord}_{r}p = n \rbrace|$$
for a fixed prime number $p$ and a natural number $n$?

I have a feeling that you might want to try this on overflow,  if you're going to get anywhere at all.  It looks hard.
